# I made it home safe vs I made it home safely

Tags: verbs, adverbs, secondary-predicates

Which, if any, of these sentences are correct:

> I made it home safe.

or

> I made it home safely.

I know that in the second example safely is an adverb, but I don't know about the first. Is it a state-of-being verb (ie. "I am safe")? Incorrect? Which sentence(s) is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I made it home safe* is acceptable grammar: *safe* does not describe the manner in which you made it home but the state in which you arrived. These constructions are called [secondary-predicates](/questions/tagged/secondary-predicates).

Compare:

> I made it home unhurt.
>   I made it home bruised but happy.
>   I made it home depressed.

Comment: The form of the word is known as **flat adverb** or **bare adverb** when the *-ly* is stripped off.

Comment: @Peter I disagree. These are predicate adjectives, not adverbs.

Comment: @StoneyB I thought the predicate adjective wanted a copula; does _made it_ qualify?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Practically any verb could in theory sustain a secondary predicate. A copula, in the sense in which grammar borrowed the notion from logic, isn't quite the same thing as what grammarians call 'copular' verbs. And predicates don't really require predicators--a bare comma will suffice.

Comment: So! in _"I made it home as safe as possible"_ we have the flat adverb; in _"I made it home safe"_ we have the predicate adjective. What say you? (I came across an interesting piece on this distinction **[here](http://www.alphadictionary.com/blog/?p=230)**, but haven't yet digested it fully.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant I say both those *safe*s are PAs. *as..as* doesn't discriminate.

Comment: This is an interest terminology tilt, since it seems that many instances I find referred to as the _flat adverb_ could as easily be called _predicate adjectives_.

Comment: Aha. @Peter -  _safe_ is an adjective modifying _I_ in that sentence, not a _flat adverb_ modifying _made it._ In _I made it home quick,_ though, _quick_ is a flat sdverb.

Comment: How would I write that I made something safe against homes? Admited, one probably never would say that, but when I read "I made it home safe" I took it as finished the protection of something against "homes".

Comment: @P.E.Dant UNLESS: You were denying an allegation that you made it home dead. :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the correct sentence is

> I made it home safely

as it is an adverb and describes how you got home. However, many people would say

> I made it home safe

and they would still be understandable, although it is not correct grammatically. "Safe" is an adjective, what is it describing?

Comment: +1.  After I made it home safely, **I** was safe at home.

Comment: "I made it **safely** home." is also correct. Safe describes your *state* after  getting home. "I made it home **safe** *(and sound)*".